# asset:precompile for .js files? rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

## Question:

**How do you get the asset pipeline to process *all* your .js files?** (I want them served individually, not bundled into application.js)

I'm getting a ton of 404's for the javascript files that my pages are trying to reference:

```
GET http://<myStagingServer>.heroku.com/assets/<javascriptFilename1_MD5fingerprint> 404 (Not Found)
GET http://<myStagingServer>.heroku.com/assets/<SubDir>/<javascriptFilename2_MD5fingerprint> 404 (Not Found)
```

I tried adding this to `config/application.rb`:

```
config.assets.precompile << '*.js'
```

But that didn't do anything as far as I can tell.

## Background:

I'm upgrading from Rails 3.0 to 3.1 and enabling the asset pipeline.

#### Highlights so far:

- Switching to Heroku's Cedar stack from Bamboo: `heroku create --stack cedar`.
- Switching to "thin" as the production server, which fixed various issues: `gem 'thin'`.
- Moving my assets from `public/assets` to `app/assets`, updating references in code to use `stylesheet_link_tag` and `javascript_include_tag`. (Plus whatever I did for images -- they work.)
- Removing x_sendfile_header config options because [Heroku doesn't support it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597812/image-showing-as-blank-in-rails-3-1-on-production-heroku).

#### Relevant files:

```
//  
// application.js  
//  
//= require_self  
//
```

Comment: I don't know what compiling means for .js and .css.  I think I'm going to learn something here.

Comment: Show us your application.js/css

Comment: @duffymo: Heh -- I only mean that I want them to be picked-up by Sprockets (I think), given and MD5 fingerprint, and then moved to the appropriate folder.

Comment: I think I'd rephrase my question, unless this is common usage of that word by Rails afficionadoes.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, I just noticed that I had been using "require_tree ." instead of "require_self" in application.js, so I changed it. Now my development environment works, but I'm still getting errors on staging/production.

Comment: Better, I guess.  You'll find out from the responses you get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OMG: I found the problem:

## **javascripts and stylesheets with periods in their names *require* explicit extensions**

For example:

```
# WORKS
javascript_include_tag "application"
stylesheet_link_tag "application"

# BROKEN
javascript_include_tag "jueryui.custom"
stylesheet_link_tag "jueryui.custom"

# WORKS
javascript_include_tag "jueryui.custom.js"
stylesheet_link_tag "jueryui.custom.css"
```

I guess I can see why this is, but I think that it isn't very well documented on any of the asset pipeline tutorials. Is it common knowledge that you shouldn't have periods in your asset filenames?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the following in both application.js and application.css :

//= require_tree .

This loads all the files in the assets directory for CSS and JS.

Also for upgrading to 3.1 and info on the asset pipeline:

http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=✓&search=Asset+pipeline

Also:  [Using Rails 3.1 assets pipeline to conditionally use certain css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134034/using-rails-3-1-assets-pipeline-to-conditionally-use-certain-css)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to copy the files over individually -- not bundle them into the application asset file. You have pointed out the correct way to do the latter.